# How to detect connection closed by localhost?

Tags: c, winapi, winsock

I have write a TCP client and server in C. These software run on the same computer ONLY.

1) My TCP client send a command to the server (localhost).

2) The server works hard and give a response.

The problem is if the TCP Client closes the connection, I am unable to detect a client connection closed WHILE server is going to do its long work. I can only detect this with the SEND function, but it's too late because the server have already work.

I understand that this must be very hard to make this detection if the machines are remote. In my case, it is the same machine, which should make the task easier, but I have not found a solution ... Can be with the select function?

Thanks you.

Comment: On Posix you could set the socket to non-blocking and perform periodic reads. If you get `-1` with error EWOULDBLOCK, you know the connection is still up, and if you get `0`, you know the connection has closed. I don't know if the Windows socket API also supports non-blocking sockets. `select()` is an alternative, though a bit more complex.

Comment: @Kerrek: Yes, on winsock you can use the `ioctlsocket`and `setsockopt` functions to configure sockets, the non-blocking flag is one of the available settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with `select` like this:

- Use `select` for read events on the socket. So `select` unblocks when the socket is readable
- When a request arrives at the server, start work **in a different thread**
- When the client closes the connection, `select` will unblock and `recv` will read 0 bytes. If so, you can stop the worker thread
- If the worker thread finishes the task without being interrupted, it can send the result